# How to tune the coefficients of Polynomial Models in MatLab System Identification toolbox

Tags: transfer-function, estimation

I have such setting:
[image]

Where $Y_M(S)$ is the transfer function of the model I am trying to approximate with $Y_U(S)$, what I have is the data of the signal corrupted with noise.

I am trying to create a model using Matlab's System Identification Toolbox, but the models I am coming up with are covering 3.5% variability tops, I have no idea how to proceed.

The best fits using the "Order Selection" button in ARX are also very weak, the ARX model mostly covers the variability with minus sign.
Can explain to me how can I make a good model?

How do I tune the Parameters of ARX, ARMAX, OE and BJ?